# Insert record then delete older duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm adding data to a db table one records at a time. After adding each record I need to check if the same item is already in the database. Whilst their may be multiple entries for the item, all column data other than 'reference' may be different in each record.

So far I have the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertAcListingsAircraftData]
....
AS

INSERT INTO tblRes (....)
VALUES (.....)

DELETE FROM tblRes 
WHERE Id NOT IN
(
    SELECT MAX(Id)
    FROM tblRes 
    GROUP BY reference
)
```

So, the aim is to insert the record then group all records together via the 'name' column. Then return the id of the most recently entered row for that named item.

Assuming that I am on the right track with the code above, what is the best way to grab the Id of the inserted row, and then use it in the delete statement?

Am I heading in the right direction?

### Edit

I've changed the delete statement to this:

```
DELETE FROM tblRes 
WHERE SCOPE_IDENTITY NOT IN
(
    SELECT MAX(Id)
    FROM tblRes 
    GROUP BY reference
)
```

Will this now do the job?

Comment: Why not DELETE any older ones first, then INSERT?

Comment: yes ! Delete first, then insert, and put the whole thing in a transaction

Comment: Don't use @@Identity here. You should instead use SCOPE_IDENTITY. If you have a trigger on the table you insert to that has an identity you will get the identity value from that table when using @@Identity. SCOPE_IDENTITY will return the latest identity from the current scope.

Comment: @SeanLange You are correct. I actually knew that but forgot to engage my brain. Thanks for helping me avoid a small disaster.

Comment: @user2338816 Because I don't know if Ive got any duplicates until I add it. Also, if there was a failure to insert, then all records for that item would be removed. Yes I could use commits, but in this instance I want to keep it simple and limit scope for issues.

Comment: @user2338816 Also, I like to learn from scenarios and think of alternate ways to doing things, rather than using the simplest crudest method time and again.

Comment: But what if DELETE goes wrong? Would it be fine to keep duplicates?

Comment: @AndriyM It'd be better than not having any record for an item.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: you mean it would *not* be fine but it would be better than having no record at all? Is your question then about choosing the lesser of two evils rather than about finding an objectively sane approach? It is up to you if you want to stick with a particular pattern, certainly, I'm just trying to make these things clear (for others as well as for myself).

Comment: @AndriyM Im sure Ive explained it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM tblRes 
WHERE SCOPE_IDENTITY NOT IN
(
    SELECT MAX(Id)
    FROM tblRes 
    GROUP BY reference
)
```

Comment: If you want to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` somehow, you need to additionally limit the rows you are deleting to those that have the same `reference` as the last inserted row. As written, your condition will be true either for all rows in the table or for none, likely the former (assuming the preceding INSERT was successful).

Answer (score 3):

If the Id column is an identity then you can use @@IDENTITY to return the Id of the row that was inserted last.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (PK INT IDENTITY(1,1), SomeValue VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #MyTable (SomeValue) SELECT 'xxx';
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
INSERT INTO #MyTable (SomeValue) SELECT 'yyy';
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

Returns 1, then 2.

So, to use this in your original stub:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertAcListingsAircraftData]
....
AS

INSERT INTO tblRes (....)
VALUES (.....)

DECLARE @Id INT;
SELECT @Id = @@IDENTITY;
DECLARE @Reference NVARCHAR(MAX); --or whatever data type it is
SELECT @Reference = Reference FROM tblRes WHERE Id = @Id;    

DELETE FROM tblRes 
WHERE Reference = @Reference 
AND Id != @Id;
```

...or something along those lines?

Comment: My issue is in catching the identity to then use in the Delete statement.

Comment: How about this? DELETE FROM acResults
 WHERE @@IDENTITY NOT IN
 (
  SELECT MAX(Id)
  FROM acResults
  GROUP BY acID
 )

Comment: I edited my answer, you said Reference was the common field, I might have misunderstood that?

Comment: Sorry, yes! Ive not helped by mixing up pseudo code and real code. Thanks!

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY is more appropriate here than @@IDENTITY.

Answer (score 1):

Try following query:

```
DELETE z
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY Id DESC)row
    FROM yourtable
    )z
WHERE z.rowr<>1
```

EDIT: You can use following format in order to delete older rows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertAcListingsAircraftData]
....
AS

DECLARE @T TABLE(Id int)

INSERT INTO tblRes (....)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @T
VALUES (.....)

DELETE FROM tblRes 
WHERE name= @name
  and Id NOT IN(SELECT Id FROM @T)
```

Comment: Thanks. I dont fully understand what this does so forgive my ignorance. But, it looks like this will delete all records for all items other than the most recently added. I just need to delete all duplicate older entries for the newly added item.

Comment: @PhillHealey. I Edit my query. Please check again.

Comment: Would that not delete EVERY record except the one that has just been inserted?

Comment: @mehdilotfi That still doesnt look correct to me. It looks like it would delete everything except the most recently added record/id